# How to open multiple tabs in Google Chrome using a Macro

Tags: excel, google-chrome

I need help with my schooling, I stay very busy and most of the time fall behind, I use Excel to keep track of my grades and other necessities, but what I need is a way to open Chrome with three tabs to specific websites they will be below. I don't have my current code with me at the time this was made, but I got as far to open chrome on one of the links, I plan to put use a command button to run it. I desperately need help, and anything will do.

I will post a copy of my current code when able.

Links:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator

https://auth.edgenuity.com/Login/Login/Student

The third is Bing...I was limited on links because I am new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the **Shell** property:

```
Sub Chrome()

Dim cpath As String

gpath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""

Shell (cpath & " -url https://www.desmos.com/calculator")
Shell (cpath & " -url https://auth.edgenuity.com/Login/Login/Student")
Shell (cpath & " -url http://stackoverflow.com/")

End Sub
```

Note that if your chrome.exe file is stored somewhere else other than the standard path, you need to update the path above.

Comment: My pleasure @Quinn.Wolf

Comment: Can you tell me how to open multiple browsers at once...
The above works excellent, but I would like half of them to appear in one browser and the others to appear in the other. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a way to check what browser the user is using and open the browser accordingly. But you could open a new threat with the code and ask other users.